# How to hide rows in a form until they are clicked using javascript.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to hide rows until they are clicked. I didn't initially write the code and I was having hard time fixing the issues. It's for an advanced order form for a private jet company. The form is supposed to have only 2 visible legs and then you'll be able to click on add a leg button to add a leg, instead it shows 15 legs.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.trip-type').change(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "multi-leg") {
            jQuery("#addleg").css("display", "block").hide().end();
            for (var i = 2; i <= 3; i++) {
                jQuery('.to_leg_' + i).val('');
                jQuery('.to_leg_' + i).attr('data-code', "");
                jQuery('.to_leg_' + i).attr('data-name', "");
                jQuery('.to_leg_' + i).attr('data-real-city', "");
                jQuery('.to_leg_' + i).attr('data-country', "");
                jQuery('.to_leg_' + i).attr('data-latitude', "");
                jQuery('.to_leg_' + i).attr('data-longitude', "");
            }
            for (var n = 3; i <= 5; i++) {
                jQuery('.from_leg_' + i).val('');
                jQuery('.from_leg_' + i).attr('data-code', "");
                jQuery('.from_leg_' + i).attr('data-name', "");
                jQuery('.from_leg_' + i).attr('data-real-city', "");
                jQuery('.from_leg_' + i).attr('data-country', "");
                jQuery('.from_leg_' + i).attr('data-latitude', "");
                jQuery('.from_leg_' + i).attr('data-longitude', "");
            }
            var allElements = jQuery('#multileg-block').find("div.row");
            for (var i = 0; n < allElements.length; i++) {
                if (jQuery(allElements[i]).hasClass("non-one-way") === true) {
                    jQuery(allElements[i]).removeClass('non-one-way');
                    jQuery(allElements[i]).removeClass(i);
                    jQuery(allElements[i]).css("display", "none");
                    jQuery(allElements[i]).attr('attribute', "");
                }
            }
            var trelements = jQuery('#multi-table').find("tbody tr.multileg-table");
            for (var i = 1; i < trelements.length; i++) {
                if (jQuery(trelements[i]).hasClass('non-one-way') === true) {
                    jQuery(trelements[i]).removeClass("non-one-way");
                    jQuery(trelements[i]).css("display", "none");
                    jQuery(trelements[i]).attr('attribute', "");
                }
            }

            $('.info-distances tbody tr.multileg-info:eq(0)').addClass('non-one-way');
        } else {
            jQuery("#addleg").css("display", "none");
            jQuery('.info-distances tbody tr:eq(1)').removeClass('non-one-way');
            var mutrelements = jQuery('.info-distances').find("tbody tr.multileg-info");
            for (var i = 1; i < mutrelements.length; i++) {
                if (jQuery(mutrelements[i]).hasClass('non-one-way') === true) {
                    jQuery(mutrelements[i]).removeClass("non-one-way");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    jQuery('#addleg').on("click", function () {
        var allElements = jQuery('#multileg-block').find("div.row");
        for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
            if (jQuery(allElements[i]).hasClass("non-one-way") == false) {
                jQuery(allElements[i]).addClass('non-one-way');
                jQuery(allElements[i]).addClass(i);
                jQuery(allElements[i]).css("display", "block");
                jQuery(allElements[i]).attr('attribute', i);
                break;
            }
        }
        var trelements = jQuery('#multi-table').find("tbody tr.multileg-table");

        for (var i = 0; i < trelements.length; i++) {
            if (jQuery(trelements[i]).hasClass('non-one-way') === false) {
                jQuery(trelements[i]).addClass("non-one-way");
                jQuery(trelements[i]).css("display", "table-row");
                jQuery(trelements[i]).attr('attribute', i);
                break;
            }
        }

        var mutrelements = jQuery('.info-distances').find("tbody tr.multileg-info");
        for (var i = 1; i < mutrelements.length; i++) {
            if (jQuery(mutrelements[i]).hasClass('non-one-way') === false) {
                jQuery(mutrelements[i]).addClass("non-one-way");
                break;
            }
        }


    });
    jQuery('.Leg_remove').on("click", function () {
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().removeClass('non-one-way');
        index = parseInt(jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr('attribute'));
        jQuery('.non-one-way[attribute=' + index + ']').removeClass('non-one-way').css('display', 'none');
        index += 2;
        jQuery('.info-distances tbody tr:eq(' + index + ')').removeClass('non-one-way');


    });
}); < /script>
```

Comment: Well... this is a truly **workaround oriented-programming**. In fact, there is an event in jQuery you can use do dinamically hide and show rows, depends on which class or id you've set. But you need to think first when the beginning of the general activity of attitudes training positively. For this issue, try to search about `slideToggle()` and you will be successfully in your code that affects the correct prediction of the tables and rows and administrative requirements for user.

Comment: Thank you, But I don't know where to add that in the above code to make it work...

Comment: First. I will suggest you to remove all `for` statements that possibly locks temporary your browser and treat all rows in PHP. After that, create an input hidden for each row that contains an increment ID. this ID will be treated in your jQuery script. You will save a lot of Javascripts line

Comment: I hate to have to repeat this... I am new to this style of coding could you possibly show me an example